Diesel Migrations: Solution for table creation & column addition?
I'm working on a Diesel project and want to streamline my migrations. Ideally, I'd like a single up.sql file that can handle both creating the table and adding new columns later. Is there a recommended approach to achieve this in Diesel, or do I need separate migrations for table creation and column additions?
My idea is to make it easy to add columns to the table just by specifying the column to be added and run the migration to apply the same.
Any advice or best practices would be appreciated!

Each migration should change the database from what your previous code expected to what your new code expects, a single transaction that creates a fresh database or just adds new columns to an existing one seems counter to their entire point.

Do you know flyway? Also refinery seems to be Rust's industry standard.

Diesel migrations can be any valid SQL, meaning you can either define your tables and add columns in one file, or in separate files. Either will work.
The important part is that your Rust code uses the updated schema.rs file to make sure you get the proper type checking that Diesel grants you.
Diesel is also designed to have an entire directory of migrations that don't change once they have been created. This is intended so you can recreate an empty copy of your production database on any server using diesel setup. You can also have the migration run as soon as your web server starts, automating SQL deployment to production.
Modifying a single migration file breaks this pattern (since the migration is marked as done and will not be re-run unless you use diesel database reset, or diesel migration redo, both of which will likely cause your tables to be dropped and your data to be lost) and if that is what you want to do then Diesel may not be the tool for you.
